# Display collections on my website using Flickr API

Tags: php, collections, flickr, phpflickr

I have been looking for a long time where I could find a php script using phpflickr class (or not) in order to display collections (titles, images or both) on my website.

I can't find any.

If anyone has idea...

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Pico

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you can live without the phpflickr class, there's an alternative way to do that using PHP's SimpleXML. Here's a link I googled for your convenience. It has a working demo and sourcecode: http://www.ifadey.com/2010/04/get-flickr-images-using-simplexml/ (dated April 27, 2010).

And if you really want to stick with your phpflickr class, check http://www.adambate.com/how-to-add-a-flickr-based-photo-gallery-to-your-website-phpflickr-lightbox/ (dated June 6, 2009) which I - again - found with a simple google search. This one has a working example with sourcecode too, and even some info what to do if you’re looking to only display one set.

That should get you going...